# UIWebView enable/disable back/forward buttons

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

On the iPad I get weird situations with enabling and disabling the back/forward buttons. When web view starts and finishes the load, I check to enable/disable them based on canGoBack and canGoForward. But most of the time the buttons are enabled when they shouldn't be and disabled when they shouldn't be. Like on google, if I type something, no delegates are called so the buttons are disabled. In Safari their back/forward button changes. And if I go to a page on google, then back twice I'm on the first page again and my back button is still on. Is there a way to know when going back a page finished loading (seems like it doesn't call the delegate on back?) or know when canGoBack and canGoForward change YES/NO?

Comment: Is your question about enabling/disabling UI controls or the UIWebView functionality??

Comment: No its about UIWebview and being able to detect a change. The web view delegates are less called on iPad because the sites dont fully load a page or something. So a google search never calls the start or finish delegates. I figured out the answr to my question though.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate methods – webViewDidStartLoad: and – webViewDidFinishLoad: are not called sometimes, like on a google search. but i found out that – webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: is called, so i can change the buttons and page title from that method now.